# How to generate random LatLng coordinates in a polygon?

Tags: android

I need to generate random LatLng points in a polygon defined on the maps 
suppose my first point beging at (x,y) and next latlng will be greater than 100 meters and less that 500 meters

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like below, this uses a HashMap to create unique and random numbers:

```
public void getRandomPosistions(int endPoint, int total)
{
    Set<Point> set = new HashSet<Point>();
    Random position = new Random();
    Point point;

    Point usedPos = new Point();
    // Starting Position
    usedPos.x = 100;
    usedPos.y = 100;
    set.add(usedPos);

    do
    {
        point = new Point();
        point.x=position.nextInt(endPoint);
        point.y=position.nextInt(endPoint);
        set.add(point);
    }
    while(set.size() < (total));

    List<Object> positionList = new ArrayList<Object>(set);
}
```

Comment: All that's doing is generating a bunch of random points (values from 0 to 2^32), Definitely not what the question asked for.

Comment: Yes but you can add dynamic integers in so that you start and end point are getting a random number between correct point. e.g end point can be 500 + startPoint etc. The above is a rough logic to implement.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple.

1. Get maximum and minimum values of latitude and longitude.
2. generate random value of longitude (use uniform distribution).
3. generate random value of latitude (you can use uniform distribution or take into account shape of the earth).
4. check if random point is inside of polygon, if not then try again.